# Отправить одно фото или видео если это не альбом telethon

Tags: python, telebot, бот, telethon

Для примера возьмем обычный кусок кода telethon, мне надо что бы при новом посте в моём канале,бот отправлял этот пост мне в другой канал,всё просто,но когда дело касается поста в котором группа фото или видео(альбом),то бот сначала отсылает по отдельности файлы которые были в посте,и только потом отсылает сам альбом.К примеру я публикую пост в канал с 2 фотками, по идее бот должен понять что это альбом и переслать его в мой другой канал,но нет,как я говорил ранее он отсылает их по отдельности и лишь потом сам альбом.Я чувствую что я что-то не так понимаю и делаю.Помогите пожалуйста,буду очень благодарен

```
client = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash)
print('started...')

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=channels))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    if event.message.media:
        await client.send_file(my_channel_id, file=event.message, caption=desc, parse_mode='HTML',)
     
@client.on(events.Album(chats=channels))
async def handler(event):
    await client.send_message(
        my_channel_id,
        file=event.messages,
        message=desc,
        parse_mode='HTML',
    )
 
client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте проверку на наличие атрибута `grouped_id` - `if not event.grouped_id`, он присутствует в группе сообщений с альбома, а у обычного сообщения (не альбома) отсутствует.

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=channels))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    if event.message.media and not event.grouped_id: # <- альбомы обрабатываться не будут
        await client.send_file(my_channel_id, file=event.message, caption=desc, parse_mode='HTML',)
```